# How to prevent code stripping with IL2CPP?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, socket.io, apk

We are making our first small Unity Android game. App connects to our Socket.IO server and sends/receives some data. Everything works fine during development. We connect device via USB, use Unity Remote 5 on device, app connects to server and everything is great.

Then we build signed APK from Unity. We install APK to same device, app starts without problem, but socket.io communication doesn't work. At server side, I can see initial request to connect (which is successful), but then app won't connect to specified namespace, and it doesn't send requests to load data.

Are we making some obvious mistake? Do we have to specify something else to build working APK? We are only adding keystore to sign release. It seems that network communication is enabled in release APK, because we see some requests. We are Unity beginners, any help is appreciated.

We use Unity 2019.1.11f1. We use this socket.io client library: https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp

We have tried other library: https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet but encountered same problem. Works during development, doesn't work in release APK. We have also tried 2 different Socket.IO server implementation, both (Flask and go-socket.io) behaved same.

EDIT: We have done more testing and found out, that when using Mono, everything works fine. But when we switch to IL2CPP, APK is broken. 
We have to use IL2CPP because of Play store (required 64-bit). Our current theory is too aggressive code stripping that removes some important part of code.

So, question should be, how to prevent code stripping with IL2CPP?

Comment: anything in the device log? https://answers.unity.com/questions/492681/how-to-use-adb-logcat.html

Comment: thanks, we will check that today

Comment: @Kubik Have you tried FM WebSocket? It supports many platforms with Socket.IO setup.
youtube ref: https://youtu.be/82_-a7WF3vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's actually in any way related to your issues, but code stripping has a proper setting in the engine:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html

Comment: This seems to be the right way, but we were unable to figure out which class/file/assembly exactly is being stripped. So we have scrapped Unity project and rewrote whole app in native Android without 3d support. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @Kubik as far as I know, if the code stripping in unity is enabled, then Unity strips everything that's not used, from all the DLLs (including external ones, its own engine internal ones, everything), and I think it's on the level of functions. Sorry to hear you've dropped Unity because of this issue, but happy to hear you've solved the problem in some way.